# (node) sys is deprecated. Use util instead. - Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: node.js, npm, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

Personally, I have a problem when compiling in my studio titanium ...

**(node) sys is deprecated. Use util instead.**

I have no idea of what might be ... need help ....

```
(node) sys is deprecated. Use util instead.
/Users/silviosampaio/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-ios-device/ios-device.js:49
        throw new Error('Missing compatible node-ios-device library');
        ^
Error: Missing compatible node-ios-device library
    at loadIosDeviceModule (/Users/silviosampaio/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-ios-device/ios-device.js:49:9)
    at Object.devices (/Users/silviosampaio/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-ios-device/ios-device.js:66:2)
    at Object.detect (/Users/silviosampaio/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/device.js:68:12)
    at devices (/Users/silviosampaio/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/index.js:102:11)
    at /Users/silviosampaio/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:570:21
    at /Users/silviosampaio/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:249:17
    at /Users/silviosampaio/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:125:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/Users/silviosampaio/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:24)
    at async.each (/Users/silviosampaio/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:124:9)
---------------------------------------------
    at Object.run (/Users/silviosampaio/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:59:8)
    at find (/Users/silviosampaio/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:96:14)
    at /Users/silviosampaio/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:945:13
    at Immediate.q.process (/Users/silviosampaio/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:913:25)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
---------------------------------------------
    at Object.setImmediate (/Users/silviosampaio/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:200:9)
    at _insert (/Users/silviosampaio/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:861:19)
    at Object.q.push (/Users/silviosampaio/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:888:17)
    at Object.findExecutable (/Users/silviosampaio/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:113:8)
    at resolveNode (/Users/silviosampaio/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js:97:34)
    at /Users/silviosampaio/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js:74:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/silviosampaio/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js:80:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
2015-11-26T02:57:17.679Z | TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
2015-11-26T02:57:17.680Z | ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/silviosampaio/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:92:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
2015-11-26T02:57:17.680Z | TRACE  | Sending exit signal to titanium process:  63173
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Comment: What version of NodeJS do you use? Titanium 4.0.x supports NodeJS >= 0.10.0 <= 0.12.x

Comment: Use the newest version of titanium sdk, which is 5.1.1 at the time of writing. Update your `tiapp.xml` with this: `<sdk-version>5.1.1.GA</sdk-version>`

Answer (score 2):

A possible reason for this error is that each Titanium version seems to have a small range of [support for different xcode versions](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Titanium+Compatibility+Matrix#TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Xcode). To fix this you just need to install the version that supports your currently installed xcode version.

**Studio**

In the studio you can do this by selecting `check for titanium sdk updates`. You may also need update the `sdk-version` in your `tiapp.xml`.

**Open source CLI**

For people using the open source CLI you can install it like so:

```
titanium sdk install --branch 5_1_X --default
```